# Ace Editor AddCommand - How to invoke external function

Tags: editor, ace-editor, custom-function

I am using Ace editor in a web app I am developing. I have a Save button that calls a function I wrote called `handleFileUpdate()`. But, I also want the user to be able to save the contents by a keyboard shortcut.

Here is my current code for the Ace keybinding:

```
    this.editor.commands.addCommand({
      name: 'save',
      bindKey: {win: "Ctrl-S", "mac": "Cmd-S"},
      exec: function(editor) {
        this.handleFileUpdate();
      }
    });
```

where `this.handleFileUpdate()` is a function in my own code.

When the command is invoked, Ace throws this error:

`TypeError: this.handleFileUpdate is not a function. (In 'this.handleFileUpdate()', 'this.handleFileUpdate' is undefined)`

I understand that `this.handleFileUpdate()` is not visible to Ace.

My question is: how is it possible for an Ace command to invoke an external function?  Or put another way, how is it possible to provide a custom function to Ace so it can invoke it when Ctrl-S is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not so much a question about ace, as about this handling in javascript.

In your example this in the internal function is the object on which the method is defined.

As a workaround you can use an arrow function.

```
    this.editor.commands.addCommand({
      name: 'save',
      bindKey: {win: "Ctrl-S", "mac": "Cmd-S"},
      exec: (editor) => {
        this.handleFileUpdate();
      }
    })
``~
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  That worked.